# Oracle Mobile Application framework license

Tags: java, oracle

hello any body know how to get commercial license for MAF. I want license for this to create application

Comment: Consider asking your question on the Oracle MAF Community forum: https://community.oracle.com/community/oracle-mobile/oraclemaf

Comment: Contact a local Oracle reseller and ask. AFAIK it's priced per app at 50K but I might be totally wrong since their pricing/licensing confuses the hell out of me. BTW I work for a company called [Codename One](https://www.codenameone.com/) which is essentially Java on mobile. Did you look at that?

Comment: Yes I am using code name one and is quite good